# '/' or '\' for paths?

Tags: python, backslash, slash

I am having this problem when sharing files with my friends...

I have windows, some use mac and others Linux. When I share python files that contain commands of creating directories, like for instance:

```
Path_Results = os.path.dirname(Path_Definition)+'\Results'
```

the directory is not created because in Windows \ is used, whereas in mac and linux / are used.
Any ideas how can I create a more general script ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at `pathlib`

Comment: BTW, a path like `C:/projects/stackoverflow/6500219/` will work in Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pathlib.Path`. Then you'll stop concerning yourself with `/` or `\`

On Windows:

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> updir = Path("..")
>>> resdir = updir / "Result"
>>> resdir
WindowsPath('../Result')
>>> str(resdir)
'..\\Result'
```

On Linux, Mac, BSD, and other *nix:

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> updir = Path("..")
>>> resdir = updir / "Result"
>>> resdir
PosixPath('../Result')
>>> str(resdir)
'../Result'
```

Nearly all stdlib modules and functions accept `Path` as is, no need to `str()` it. Example:

```py
from pathlib import Path
resdir = Path("../Result")
filepath = resdir / "somefilename.txt"
assert isinstance(filepath, Path)
with open(filepath, "rt") as fin:
    for ln in fin:
        # do things
```

Provided there's a file `..\Result\somefilename.txt` (in Windows) or `../Result/somefilename.txt` (in Linux/Mac/BSD), the code will work exactly the same.

---

**Edit:** For your particular code:

```py
from pathlib import Path

...

# Assuming `Path_Definition` is not a Path object
Path_Results = Path(Path_Definition) / 'Results'
```

Answer (score 3):

`os.sep` exists for this very purpose. You can also use `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 0):

Its not good idea to use '/' or '' directly. path separator mentioned by @mrks is what we need to use.